# Does Factory Method violate the dependency inversion principle?

Tags: java, dependency-inversion

```
public class DependentPizzaStore {
  public Pizza createPizza(String type) {
    Pizza pizza = null;
    if (Style.equals("NY")) {
      if (type.equals("cheese")) {
        pizza = new NYStyleCheesePizza();
      }
      else if(type.equals("Veggie")){
        pizza = new NYStyleVeggiePizza();
      }
    }

    pizza.prepare();
    pizza.bake();
    pizza.cut();
    pizza.box();
    return pizza;
  }
}
```

This example from Headfirst Design Patterns violates the "Dependency Inversion Principle", which is "Depend upon abstractions. Do not depend upon concrete classes".

The example above violates the rules because DependentPizzaStore (high-level component) depends on the concrete implementations of pizzas (low-level components).

To fix this we use the Factory Method pattern.

```
public abstract class PizzaStore {
  protected abstract Pizza createPizza(String item);
  public Pizza orderPizza(String type) {
    Pizza pizza = createPizza(type);
    System.out.println("--- Making a " + pizza.getName() + " ---");
    pizza.prepare();
    pizza.bake();
    pizza.cut();
    pizza.box();
    return pizza;
  }

  public class NYPizzaStore extends PizzaStore {
    protected Pizza createPizza(String item) {
      Pizza pizza = null;
      if (item.equals("cheese")) {
        pizza = new CheesePizza();
      } else if (item.equals("veggie")) {
        pizza = new VeggiePizza();
      }
      return pizza;
    }   
  }
```

Now PizzaStore (high-level component) depends only on Pizza abstraction of Pizza concrete classes and also concrete Pizzas depend on pizza abstraction because they extend it.

**My question is: Does the NYPizzaStore class also violate the "Dependency Inversion Principle" because it depends on CheesePizza() and VeggiePizza() which are concrete implementations of Pizza.**

Comment: You'll never get anything done if you keep avoiding concrete classes.  You have to start using them sometime.

Comment: doesn't this example lend itself to the builder pattern?  i'll troll along now...

Answer (score 0):

According to me, DIP is applicable within your main program part. You have to wonder :

**Where is the code that traduces my objective ?**

In your case, your objective is to allow to create pizza while following some rules and without depending on knowledge of what pizza you are building.

Thus, DIP should be applied to your PizzaStore class. But all classes that you use to achieve this goal, are simply some kinds of "plugins" and therefore, there're no obligatory needs to use DIP.

Indeed, within all type of programs, there must be at least one place for simple series of if/else containing concrete classes otherwize you could never end up with a finished product. Even the most perfect code cannot be "abstract" at 100%.